Water overflow circuit using um66 and bc547
I want to make a water overflow detector in overhead tank. Two wires will be immersed in the tank and when wires get dipped in water, a melody sound should play. I have got the following components and a circuit was made and it plays perfectly (but its already a closed circuit). Now I am confused how to change this circuit to get two wires that can be immersed in water (so that melody plays only when the tank is full and detection wires are submerged)?

bc547
um66
1.5 kohm resistor
speaker
5 volt batter

Here is the current circuit :


UM66's maximum operating voltage is 4.5 VDC. With the components you have it doesn't seem to be possible to build a safely-operating circuit. Is it possible to add more components to your BoM list? I'll post an answer accordingly.

I meansured my power supply and its 4.65 vdc. I think this can be tolerated by UM66

I have a 2 watt 220 ohm resistor, maybe that can be added in series/parallel to drop voltage ?

I think what's required in my circuit is a way to activate the playback (um66) with a small current that passes through the water between detection wires.
